# Segmentation fault : move assignment operator

Tags: c++

I am trying to write simple program by adding move constructor and move assignment operator . and I am checking using valgrind for memory leak . I am facing some error . May i know where I am doing mistake to resolve issue without any memory leak for all copy & move constructor as well as assignment operator ??? Can I get solution for this ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class MY{
    int **p;
    public:
        MY(){
            cout << "Default Constructor" << endl;
            p = new int*[4];
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
                p[i] = new int[5];
        }
        // Copy Constructor
        MY(const MY& obj){
            cout << "Copy Constructor" << endl;
            p = new int*[4];
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
                p[i] = new int[5];

            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
                    p[i][j] = obj.p[i][j];
            }
        }
        // Copy Assignment Operator
        MY& operator = (const MY & obj){
            cout << "Copy Assignment Opearator" << endl;

            if(this == &obj)
                return *this;

            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
                delete [] p[i];
            delete [] p;

            p = new int*[4];
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
                p[i] = new int[5];

            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
                    p[i][j] = obj.p[i][j];
            }
            return *this;
        }
        // Move Constructor
        MY(MY && obj){
            cout << "Move Constructor" << endl;
            p = obj.p;
            obj.p = nullptr;
        }
        // Move Assignment Operator
        MY& operator = (MY && obj){
            cout << "Move Assignement Operator" << endl;
            if(this == &obj)
                return *this;
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
                delete [] p[i];
            delete [] p;
            p = obj.p;
            obj.p = nullptr;

            return *this;
        }

        ~MY(){
            cout << "Destructor " << endl;
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
                delete [] p[i];
            delete [] p;    
        }
        void setData(){
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
                    p[i][j] = i*j;
            }
        }
        void printData(){
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
                    cout << p[i][j] << " ";
                cout << endl;    
            }
        }
};

int main()
{
    MY obj;
    obj.setData();
    obj.printData();

    // MY coj(obj);
    // coj.printData();

    // MY aoj ;
    // aoj = obj;
    // aoj.printData();

    MY moj(std::move(obj));
    moj.printData();

    MY loj;
    loj = std::move(obj);
    loj.printData();
}
```

Comment: You're trying to dereference or delete a null pointer

Comment: `MY()` has a theoretical leak if any allocation fails, but I doubt that's your issue.

Comment: @jabaa -- deleting a null pointer is okay.

Comment: In your destructor, you are calling `delete p[i]` inside a loop, which is fine if `p` is valid, but if `p` is NULL, then that is an attempt to dereference a NULL pointer and you'll (hopefully) crash.

Comment: `MY& operator = (const MY& obj)` could simply be: `MY& operator=(MY obj) { std::swap(obj.p, p); return *this; }`.  You can see that you have duplicate code in the copy constructor and destructor, so take advantage of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your move constructor and move assignment operators both assign `nullptr` to the moved-from object's `p` member, which appears to be an invalid state. Moving from an object must leave that object in a valid state.

Since the object is in an invalid state, the next method call on it will crash. In your case, that's probably the destructor

```
    ~MY(){
        cout << "Destructor " << endl;
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            delete [] p[i];  //crash because `p` is nullptr
        delete [] p;    
    }
```

One solution is to delete the move-constructor, and then have the move-assignment use swap instead, which leaves the moved-from object in a weird, but valid, state.

```
    MY& operator = (MY && obj){
        cout << "Move Assignement Operator" << endl;
        std::swap(p, obj.p);
        return *this;
    }
```

Another option is to redesign the class so that holding `nullptr` is a valid state.

## ============

On the non-answer side of things:

1. use std::vector and std::array, and you'll never have these problems again.
2. Your copy constructor is overly complicated. It can be simple

   ```
    MY& operator = (const MY & obj){
        cout << "Copy Assignment Opearator" << endl;
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
                p[i][j] = obj.p[i][j];
        }
        return *this;
    }
   ```

Comment: I agree with std::swap option , but removing delete operation from move assignment operator function is causing more memory leak .

Comment: Did you also fix the move-constructor?  Or change the destructor?

Comment: I have putted check in destructor . Also used delete & swap operation in move assignment  operator function . Still I am facing 112 bytes lost . Any comment on this ?

Comment: I can't really comment on memory leaks in code that I haven't seen :(

Comment: How can I sent you same code for check , I am beginner .

Comment: as of now , I done changes , with this changes if I am running only move constructor or move assignment operator at a time , then I am not facing any memory leak . but if I am running both things simultaneously like i mentioned on above program , i am facing 112 bytes lost in 5 blocks , Also Program is get CRASH.

Comment: @PANKAJLADE: sounds like it's time to ask a new question.

Comment: I found solution @Moong Duck . I understood where I was doing mistake . Thank you for your help .